# How much is astrophysics, cosmology, and theoretical astrophysics on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, scope

There have been some concerns raised about cosmology and theoretical astrophysics, as well as astrophysics in general.

The concern is that this community does not support astrophysics questions, especially cosmology and theoretical astrophysics.

If you think this community can support astrophysics questions, make your case for it in an answer here. Try to bring more to bear than just "I like astrophysics, and I'm a professional and I want it here." Bring existing posts (questions AND answers) to support your view. Show us why you think this community can support these types of questions.

---

And by *support*, I mean that we actually have a sufficient userbase to **ask and *answer*** these types of questions at an **expert** level, not just show an interest in them!

Comment: Good point, as we are community driven, let the community state its case.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Summary: Yes, those are all ontopic here.

Here is a (non-exhaustive) list of astrophysical questions, with fairly good answers:

- [Why do X-ray binaries such as GRS-1915 have active and quiet states?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/528/why-do-x-ray-binaries-such-as-grs-1915-have-active-and-quiet-states)
- [Why does the Earth have a tilt of ~23°?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/537/why-does-the-earth-have-a-tilt-of-23)
- [Why is our solar system "tipped" about 63° with respect to the plane of our galaxy?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/546/why-is-our-solar-system-tipped-about-63-with-respect-to-the-plane-of-our-gala)
- [Why Did Mars lose its Magnetic Field?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/501/why-did-mars-lose-its-magnetic-field)
- [What is the current accepted theory for the fate of hot Jupiters?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/401/what-is-the-current-accepted-theory-for-the-fate-of-hot-jupiters)
- [Why is there a matter/anti-matter asymmetry in the universe?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/381/why-is-there-a-matter-anti-matter-asymmetry-in-the-universe) (cosmology)
- [What is the current accepted theory as to why Mercury, despite its size, has a similar density to Earth?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/362/what-is-the-current-accepted-theory-as-to-why-mercury-despite-its-size-has-a-s)
- [Why is the Sun's atmosphere (the corona) so hot?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/247/why-is-the-suns-atmosphere-the-corona-so-hot)
- [Two species of dark matter?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/782/two-species-of-dark-matter) (cosmology)

Plus, there are at least few people around with (or preparing) a degree in astrophysics who are able to handle this kind of questions:

- [astromax](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/users/45/astromax)
- [guillochon](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/users/2/guillochon)
- [Francesco Montesano](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/users/86/francesco-montesano)
- [UV-D](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/users/8/uv-d) (at least for planetary science/atmosphere)
- myself
- [Manishearth](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/users/28/manishearth) (Currently an undergrad, has not yet decided a field but is leaning towards astrophysics)
- [Eduardo Guerras Valera](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/users/316/eduardo-guerras-valera)
- [Freelanceastro](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/users/467/freelanceastro)

I did not check on everybody though.

Comment: Thanks, MBR! It would be helpful if you could note which ones are specifically relevant to cosmology and theoretical astrophysics as well.

Comment: @called2voyage why can I not edit this answer? Could you add this  http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/782/two-species-of-dark-matter to the list of nicely answered theoretical questions and add this newly arrived  user http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/users/316/eduardo-guerras-valera to the list of experts in cosmology and theoretical astrophysics? Thanks

Comment: @Dilaton: done!

Comment: @MBR thanks :-)

Comment: Hi MBR [here](http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/users/467/freelanceastro) has a new expert on cosmology arrived, he has already given me 2 nice answers :-)

Comment: @Dilaton: Thanks, I added him in the list!